Is there a way to COUNTIF the number of partial name matches (REGEXMATCH) within a column of cells?
Im trying to make an Absent & Late counter based off answers from a google form. The google form collects whos absent and late through checkboxes and in the linked sheets all the names are inputted as name1, name 2, name 3...
The problem I currently have is that I can't make a counter if I can't REGEXMATCH a whole column.
I tested it out with just 1 cell through this formula and it worked:
=IF(REGEXMATCH(C2,"SMITH JOHN"), COUNTIF(C2, "SMITH JOHN"))
I just need this to work for the whole column.
This is what I want to happen:
FORM DATA ON COLUMNS B, C, & D



DATE
ABSENT
LATE




09/12/23
SMITH JOHN, CRAIG AMY
HOPE MITCH


09/13/23
HOPE MITCH, SMITH JOHN
CRAIG AMY



Expected Output:
COUNTER ON COLUMNS F, G, H



NAME
ABSENT
LATE




SMITH JOHN
2
0


CRAIG AMY
1
1


HOPE MITCH
1
1



Please let me know if theres any way to achieve this!


Here's one approach using the COUNTIF function:
=map(F2:F,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,index({countif(split(C:C,", ",),Σ),countif(split(D:D,", ",),Σ)}))))



Oh wow thank you so much! This solved my issue.

You can use the following formula for ABSENT:
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(C2:C,"*"&F2:F4&"*")) 

And the following formula for LATE:
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(D2:D,"*"&F2:F4&"*"))

Or one formula for both:
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYCOL(C2:D,LAMBDA(c,COUNTIF(c,"*"&F2:F4&"*")))) 

